Expiry for tag synonym suggestions
Recently I wanted to create a tag synonym ng-modules of the angular-module tag, but I was unable to do so because apparently there is a pending tag synonym suggestion which is open for over 10 years stuck at 0 votes.
In my opinion, there should be a expiry date (i.e. 2 years) for tag synonym suggestions.
After reaching the expiry date, the suggestion should be canceled automatically, in order to unblock other tag synonym creations.

looks like there are 542 tags created over 2 years ago that have not been approved (https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1875475/2295960/)

IMO an expiry date will not fix the tag synonym system. The problem is that no-one votes or looks at suggested tag synonyms. That isn't fixed by expiring them after not getting enough votes for two years, so you can add your suggestion which will also expire after two years.

I don't think the solution to this problem should be creating a new expiry system for tag synonyms. They're already somewhat complicated:

You need rep to be able to make and vote on them
You need 5 total score in the tag to be able to vote for/create them
They need 4 score to be approved (so basically, 5 total people (minus dissenting votes) or 1 moderator who agree it should be a synonym)
They're basically hidden in the UI; there's nothing that readily surfaces them for potential reviewers, you have to manually navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested to see ones you can vote on

Adding yet another layer of complexity to this would overburden an already, at least in my view, brittle system.
The solution to this problem is to do what you've done (in a roundabout way): Signal-boost the synonym request on Meta and ask for it to be addressed in some fashion, whether that results in approval or rejection. Whatever the result of that discussion is, if there aren't enough people with the qualifications to vote on the synonym, you can ask a moderator to approve/reject it for you (a flag would probably work, but I won't speak for the SO mods' preferences on this).
Clearly the person who proposed this synonym felt it was appropriate. It should be dealt with in some capacity, not silently discarded. Meta's an acceptable venue to facilitate that.
